# What is the source and reason for the two dipping items at Pesach Seder?

Tags: passover, passover-seder-hagada, marror-bitter-herbs

I somewhat understand why many have the custom to dip things in the first place during the Pesach Seder. But, I'm curious about the source and reason for these two specific items, namely:

Why specifically use salt water and charoset? I understand the symbolism of the salt water that they represent the tears from the hard labor. The charoset is supposed to represent the paste from the mortar? But why does the charoset need to be made with fruit and nuts? If one wanted to have a paste from food, he could make a paste from potato starch or ground meat, as well. WHy use these ingredients, specifically?

Also, why specifically dip the vegetable in the salt water and the maror in charoset? Why not reverse?

Comment: Who's we? 1515.

Comment: Sigh. The goal isn't to remove the term we, but to specify to whom you do refer. Not all Jews dip in saltwater for instance.

Comment: Potato starch was not always available (we have a history and costoms), ground beef is not easily edible

Comment: @DoubleAA AFAIK, Gem. Pesachim mentions dipping, though, agreed, that I have seen some dip karpas in vinegar. Everyone I have seen dips maror in charoset. I'm unaware of anyone that uses something else. Sorry, about this kind of edit, but the best I could do is add the words "that I know" to the "many" edit.

Comment: @DanF Some dip Karpas in Charoset too.

Comment: @DoubleAA Yes! I read this on Hilchot hagada of the Ritba this Shabbat

Comment: @hazoriz "ground beef is not easily edible". What? You never had meat sauce? Can you explain what you mean by "easily". Cooked ground beef can become "spreadable" if cooked slightly / partially raw. Also, some people eat completely raw meat. I don't suggest it for the seder, but, I'm just pointing out that in terms of a paste, this is possible, perhaps.